# Android: Stopping Alarm at specific time and service clarification

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

is there any way to stop an alarm at a given time, for example, i started an alarm on 7:45am and it repeats every 5 minutes and then, i wanted to stop that alarm when the time is already 8:00am?

How do i go about this algorithm since alarm manager's cancel() method only accepts an action (PendingIntent)

and Secondly, regarding services, i have an idea to put a checker or an if statement on service to check if its already 8:00a, but im not sure if service always run in the background and if so, does that mean to say that it always checks the time if its 8am? given that meaning of services that once it started i won't stop unless explicitly told to do so.

any of you guys know any way to do this please do share, im kinda confused right now

Comment: Services can be killed when there are resources needed by the Android OS. So it could be that your service is killed just before 8:00 am.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to start the service when alarm start first time and this service will ring the alarm at 5 min and get the device time and compare it with the time to stop the time
 at that (means at 8 AM )stop your service

Comment: but services may be stopped by the android OS at any given time. so there is a chance it wont stop the alarm at the exact time as said by @PoweRoy

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you start whatever you need to do at 7:45am with [AlarmManager#setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) and set another alarm with [AlarmManager#set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) to stop the previous?

AlarmManager#set will be fired off just once, so you can use it cancel the repeating alarm

Edit:
In the implementation of `AlarmManager#set`, you would retrieve the repeating alarm(`AlarmManager#setRepeating`) and `cancel()` it

Comment: wouldn't that be redundant? adding another alarm to an existing. is there any way to only cancel an alarm?

Comment: Instead of monitoring the time which could me resources-consuming, the framework will take care of just firing off the AlarmManager#set  at the time you have defined and JUST ONCE. And it' s 2 seperate alarms

Comment: ohh? the repeating alarm can be retrieved? how would you do that?

Comment: You have to pass the exact values you have used to create your pendingIntent for the repeating alarm. This one is a bit tricky but there are lots of posts on SO with code snippets